# How do I use this Update statement in my c# code?

Tags: c#, sql

```
UPDATE Ware
SET Price = Price * 1.02
WHERE WareNr > 0 AND WareNr <= 20000 AND Price >= 200
```

This code works perfectly in my SQL server.

Now I have to put this into a c# program, and I'm not quite sure how to do it. I'm VERY new to this (got handed some basic code to do an update), but I'm just not sure on how to do this.

If someone could give me an example on how to implement that into an "update wares" button, I'd be very gratefull

Comment: Do you need to update database from your code?

Comment: You need a some kind of way to connect to database. You can use provider like ADO.NET.

Comment: What exactly is your question - perform this code on the database or do the same thing on C# types? Or something different?

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/search?q=how+to+insert+update+delete+in+asp.net&rlz=2C1OPRB_enIN0537IN0537&oq=how+to+insert+update+&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l2j69i60l2j0.14209j0j9&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8

Comment: @SurajSingh How do you even know he's using asp.net?

Comment: @JohnD what else you expect ? The link has a different message that in a single hit of google you can get most of the stuff to try, and it's just he need to do a little search that's all .

Answer (score 3):

There are a few ways to do it. You can use [`SqlConnection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`SqlCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.aspx) classes like;

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    string queryString = "UPDATE Ware SET Price = Price * 1.02 WHERE WareNr > 0 AND WareNr <= 20000 AND Price >= 200";
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
    connection.Open();
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    connection.Close();
}
```

Here the way with [`parameterized queries`](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html);

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    string queryString = "UPDATE Ware SET Price = @Price1 WHERE WareNr > @WareNr1 AND WareNr <= @WareNr2 AND Price >= @Price2";
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Price1", 100 * 1.02);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WareNr1", 0);      
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WareNr2", 20000);   
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Price2", 200);   
    connection.Open();
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    connection.Close();
}
```

- [`Data Access and Modeling`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/951h6we4%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Update your answer with parameters so that he OP can pass different values i.e WareNr, Price etc... :)

Comment: @huMptyduMpty Roger that `;)`

Answer (score 1):

```
string query = "UPDATE Ware SET Price = (Price * 1.02) WHERE WareNr > 0 AND WareNr <= 20000 AND Price >= 200";

using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("YourConnectionString"))
{
    using(SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
    {
        conn.Open();
        comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string connectionString = "Server=localhost;Database=dbName;Uid=Username;Pwd=Password";
using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    var query = @"UPDATE Ware
                    SET Price = @Price
                  WHERE WareNr > 0 AND WareNr <= 20000 AND Price >= 200";

    sqlConnection.Open();
    using (var command = new SqlCommand(query, sqlConnection))
    {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Price", 100 * 1.02);
        var dataReader = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    sqlConnection.Close();
}
```

Comment: +1 for showing a parameterized query in case it is needed.

Comment: `Price * 1.02` is very different from `100 * 1.02`. Maybe the question used to say that, or something.

Comment: @TimS. I was demonstrating a point, he can replace the figure with any variable that has a numerical data type.

Comment: With your query, you can't do what he had in the question: `Price * 1.02`. His `UPDATE` statement could update multiple `Ware`s, each to different prices. Yours can only update to a single price. That is, yours lets you set any *fixed* value, while he might instead want a *relative* value. Maybe `SET Price = Price * @PriceMultiplier` would be a better approach.

Comment: ahhhh right, I get what you meant now sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Everyone was focused on the question of how to do an update but the user asked for an example of how to do this.

"*give me an example on how to implement that into an "update wares" button*"

Here is my contribution

web.config

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="connectionString" connectionString="Persist Security Info=True;User ID=YOUR_USER_ID;Password=YOUR_PASSWORD;Initial Catalog=YOUR_DATABASE_NAME;data source=LOCALHOST;Pooling=true;Connection Lifetime=60;Max Pool Size=100;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

aspx

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    Price Rate:
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPriceRate" runat="server" />
    <br />
    New Price:
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtNewPrice" runat="server" />
    <br />
    Limit Price:
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPriceLimit" runat="server" />
    <br />
    Min WareNr:
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtWareMin" runat="server" />
    <br />
    Max WareNr:
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtWareMax" runat="server" />
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" runat="server" Text="Update" OnClick="btnUpdate_Click" />
</asp:Content>
```

aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // You will need to put some validations before try to convert the values

        try
        {
            decimal priceRate = Convert.ToDecimal(this.txtPriceRate.Text);
            decimal newPrice = Convert.ToDecimal(this.txtNewPrice.Text);
            decimal priceLimit = Convert.ToDecimal(this.txtPriceLimit.Text);
            int wareMin = Convert.ToInt32(this.txtWareMin.Text);
            int wareMax = Convert.ToInt32(this.txtWareMax.Text);

            Update(newPrice * priceRate, priceLimit, wareMin, wareMax);
        }
        catch
        {

        }
    }

    public static void Update(decimal paramPrice, decimal paramPriceLimit, int paramWareMin, int paramWareMax)
    {
        string connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connectionString"].ToString();

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            String query = "UPDATE Ware SET Price = @paramPrice WHERE WareNr > @paramWareMin AND WareNr <= @paramWareMax AND Price >= @paramPriceLimit";

            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
            command.Parameters.Add("@paramPrice", "paramPrice");
            command.Parameters.Add("@paramPriceLimit", "paramPriceLimit");
            command.Parameters.Add("@paramWareMin", "paramWareMin");
            command.Parameters.Add("@paramWareMax", "paramWareMax");

            connection.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```